# nservicebus using RabbitMQ in node.js: a non-empty message_id property is required

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, nservicebus, amqp

I am trying to get a Node.js application to communicate with another Node.js application using NServiceBus with RabbitMQ.

The problem I am finding is that in all the examples the message type has to be defined in the .NET assembly but we are not planning to use .NET.

Is there a way to specify a message type in Node.js (or other language) without having to do it in .NET?
I had a look to the unobtrusive mode but still requires configuration in your .NET application (http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/unobtrusive-mode) as far as I can see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NServiceBus is a library/platform build for .NET and is not made for Node.js.

What you can do if you really want to use NServiceBus is build most the backend of your application in .NET and let the Node.js part talk to NServiceBus via API calls (ASP.NET) or by manually making sure you put the correct json (or other format) on the RabbitMQ to be used by NServiceBus. Otherwise you can use raw AMQP and talk to RabbitMQ directly, which obviously limits you to only RabbitMQ and you'll miss all of the NServiceBus functionality.

To get certain behavior if you want to integrate with NServiceBus endpoints is to get or set headers. Read more about the specifics here http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/third-party-integrationor or here http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/headers.

Comment: Jan Pieter, can you extend our anwser with this:



To get certain behavior if you want to integrate with NServiceBus endpoints is to get or set headers:

Read about specifics here:

- http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/third-party-integration
- http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/headers

Indeed the easiest wire format to use is JSON.